# I want the sum of column B based on current year

Tags: excel, date, sum, excel-formula, sumifs

How can I get the sum of column B if the dates from Column A fall in the current year? I have a Cell to represent the current year: Cell I1 `=YEAR(TODAY())`

Comment: I am using Short Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&DATE(I1,1,1),A:A,"<="&DATE(I1,12,31))
```

[SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c59af066-13c2-47da-afe8-49c81ab233fb).

[DATE](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/DATE-function-9b619152-52d4-48f0-b1ab-a32dee59b6e4).

Comment: @pnuts can you give a little bit of explanation of the code please. It looks interesting.

Comment: @pnuts yes break it down I came close to creating this just from reverse engineering what i've seen online but what do the numbers after my Cell Date represent?  "&DATE(I1,1,1) ,<---------- what is 1, 1 for
same for &DATE(I1,31,12)) <-------------what is 31,12 ......lol nevermind I see its the first and the last day of the year ahhh this is what i was missing the whole time thank you so much!

Comment: @pnuts, I get it now. Unlike using YEAR(). User can change the range of date with this.

Comment: so you are saying that to avoid possible errors, it is better to write a fx that can deal with 1900 system. Because the date in excel is generated with "number format" (thus not pure numbers).

Answer (score 1):

In column C enter the following formula:

```
=IF(YEAR(A1)=$I$1, B1, 0)
```

Then take `SUM(C1:CN)` to get the column B sum you are after, replacing `CN` with the actual last cell you have.

Comment: Interesting.. it does get the job done but I do prefer not having to have an entire column dedicated to running this formula - but thanks i'll keep this in handy for other spreadsheets that are just for functionality and not presentation.